# polarToCart and cartToPolar functions in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Hey I've a circular image that I want to make a cartesian in openCV.

I've successfully made it on matlab however I want to do it on OpenCV.

After some digging on internet. I figured out there are actually functions called logPolar, polarToCart and cartToPolar. However OpenCV official documentation is lack of information to use them. Since I don't really understand parameters those functions take I couldn't really use them
So could someone give me (actually I think a lot of people looking for it) appropriate example to use those functions please ?
Just in case I am sharing my sample image too.

[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you're using opencv3, you probably want [linearPolar](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#linearpolar):

note, that for both versions, you need a seperate src  and dst image (does not work inplace)

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"  // needs imgproc, imgcodecs & highgui

Mat src = imread("my.png", 0); // read a grayscale img
Mat dst; // empty.
linearPolar(src,dst, Point(src.cols/2,src.rows/2), 120, INTER_CUBIC );
imshow("linear", dst);
waitKey();
```

### [image]

or [logPolar](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#logpolar):

```
logPolar(src,dst,Point(src.cols/2,src.rows/2),40,INTER_CUBIC );
```

### [image]

[edit:]

if you're still using opencv2.4, you can only use the arcane c-api functions, and need IplImage conversions (**not recommended**):

```
Mat src=...;
Mat dst(src.size(), src.type()); // yes, you need to preallocate here

IplImage ipsrc = src; // new header, points to the same pixels
IplImage ipdst = dst;


cvLogPolar( &ipsrc, &ipdst, cvPoint2D32f(src.cols/2,src.rows/2), 40, CV_INTER_CUBIC);

// result is in dst, no need to release ipdst (and please don't do so.)
```

(polarToCart and cartToPolar work on point coords, not images)

Comment: @Rodrane, still missing something ?

Comment: yeah something still missing I think its because I am using 2.4x  just downloading openCV 3 to test it out.

Comment: it worked fine on opencv 3.0 but it doesnt work on 2.4 thank you for your help!